# FB API email 'undefined' for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an MVC application and i retry Facebook value with this code:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var userId = response.authResponse.userID;
        var userToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api(
            '/' + userId,
            { fields: 'name,email,first_name,last_name' },
            function (userInfo) {
                if (userInfo && !userInfo.error) {
                    var uf = new FormData();
                    uf.append("email", userInfo.email);
                    uf.append("userId", userInfo.id);
                    uf.append("name", userInfo.name);
                    uf.append("first_name", userInfo.first_name);
                    uf.append("last_name", userInfo.last_name);
                    var url = "/Account/ExternalRegisterFacebook";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: uf,
                        error: function () {

                        },
                        success: function (responseLogin) {
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
    }
});
```

I can correctly log with my account but when i use another Facebook account i have all user value except email, that is 'undefined'.

I have read a lot of posts but i haven't understand how to solve this type of problem. I don't know if is an application error or a security information of each single Facebook profile.

Thanks to all

Comment: The email needs to be verified, otherwise it will not be returned by the API. And of course, as said here countless times before: Not every user _has_ an email address on file with Facebook, f.e. if they registered using their mobile only. So, if your app _needs_ an email address, you should implement a step for users to input it manually if necessary. (Validating/verifying it would then be your responsibility, of course.)

Comment: I used an account with only email, no mobile, and Facebook did not ask me validations in account settings. This account has two email, could it be a problem? Or the problem could be my application settings?
I can't use your solution because i use alseo"Login with Facebook" in my application

Comment: Debug your access token to make sure it includes `email` permission.

Comment: If i enter with my account i have the email correctly. If i use two other i have "undefined"

Comment: Not what I asked for.

Comment: Ok sorry. I haven't understand how to debug my access token then. Thanks for your support

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: I have done the debug of my access token with my user logged in and i have 'email' in scope of the token. I have try to use another account and do it administrator of the application and reload the accesstoken debug. Then in the second case i have the same userId with another name(the last user logged in) but i have only public_profile as scope

Comment: Well you are not asking for any permission in your FB.login call - so you only get public_profile (which is set as default for login via the web, and does not need to be specifically asked for.)

Comment: I have add , { scope: 'email' }) to the end of the FB.login function and it works. Thank you very much